# Pivot row to columns for varchar values in (Amazon Redshift)

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, pivot, amazon-redshift

The table below contains a format in which one id contains many rows.

```
select id,name,value 
from table

"id","name","value"
"a1",newsletters,true
"a1",gdpr_marketing_opt_in,true
"a1",new_widget,true
"b2",newsletters,true
"b2",newsletters_2016,true
"c3",app_shell,true
"c3",sms_reminders,true
"c3",new_widget,true
"c3",online_booking,true
"c3",merchant_shiftplan,true
```

I would like to pivot the table above into:

```
id newsletters  gdpr_marketing_opt_in new_widget  app_shell     sms_reminders   online_booking
a1    true           true              true        null            null              null
b2    true           null              null        null            null              null
c3    null           null              true        true            true              true
```

The code below returns syntax error:

```
SELECT *
from schema.table t
PIVOT
(
    max(value)
    FOR UG_LABEL IN ([newsletters], [gdpr_marketing_opt_in], [new_widget], [app_shell])
) p
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name my bad. They are three different columns. I have edited the question

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name my postgres is connected to Redshift (so as far as I understand, the crosstab that requires tablefunc) cannot be used in this case. (Redshift uses Postgres 8.0)

Comment: Please don't tag Redshift questions with Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Redshift, you can use conditional aggregation like this:

```
select id, 
       max(case when name = 'newsletters' then value end) as newsletters,
       max(case when name = 'gdpr_marketing_opt_in' then value end) as gdpr_marketing_opt_in,
       max(case when name = 'new_widget' then value end) as new_widget,
       max(case when name = 'app_shell' then value end) as app_shell,
       max(case when name = 'sms_reminders' then value end) as sms_reminders,
       max(case when name = 'online_booking' then value end) as online_booking
from the_table
group by id;
```